# How to Use Class Weights with Focal Loss in PyTorch for Imbalanced dataset for MultiClass Classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I am working on Multiclass Classification (4 classes) for Language Task and I am using the BERT model for classification task. I am following [this blog as reference](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/transfer-learning-for-nlp-fine-tuning-bert-for-text-classification/). **My BERT Fine Tuned model returns `nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)`.**

My data is pretty imbalanced so I used `sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight` to compute weights of the classes and used the weights inside the Loss.

```
class_weights = compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(train_labels), train_labels)
weights= torch.tensor(class_weights,dtype=torch.float)
cross_entropy  = nn.NLLLoss(weight=weights)
```

My results were not so good so I thought of Experementing with  `Focal Loss` and have a code for Focal Loss.

```
class FocalLoss(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, alpha=1, gamma=2, logits=False, reduce=True):
    super(FocalLoss, self).__init__()
    self.alpha = alpha
    self.gamma = gamma
    self.logits = logits
    self.reduce = reduce

  def forward(self, inputs, targets):
    BCE_loss = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()(inputs, targets)

    pt = torch.exp(-BCE_loss)
    F_loss = self.alpha * (1-pt)**self.gamma * BCE_loss

    if self.reduce:
      return torch.mean(F_loss)
    else:
      return F_loss
```

I have 3 questions now. First and the Most important is

1. **Should I use Class Weight with Focal Loss?**
2. **If I have to Implement weights inside this `Focal Loss`, can I use `weights` parameters inside  `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`**
3. If this implement is incorrect, what should be the proper code for this one including the weights (if possible)

Comment: wait, if your data is imbalanced, why did you pick 'balanced' here? I'm rather confused `compute_class_weight('balanced', np.unique(train_labels), train_labels)`

Comment: @MonaJalal `balanced` means assigning the class weight according to the Number of samples present per class? Isn't it? As [given in this documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html) **If ‘balanced’, class weights will be given by n_samples / (n_classes * np.bincount(y)).**

Answer (score 4):

You may find answers to your questions as follows:

1. Focal loss automatically handles the class imbalance, hence weights are not required for the focal loss. The alpha and gamma factors handle the class imbalance in the focal loss equation.
2. No need of extra weights because focal loss handles them using alpha and gamma modulating factors
3. The implementation you mentioned is correct according to the focal loss formula but I had trouble in causing my model to converge with this version hence, I used [the following implementation from mmdetection framework](https://github.com/open-mmlab/mmdetection/blob/master/mmdet/models/losses/focal_loss.py)

```
    pred_sigmoid = pred.sigmoid()
    target = target.type_as(pred)
    pt = (1 - pred_sigmoid) * target + pred_sigmoid * (1 - target)
    focal_weight = (alpha * target + (1 - alpha) *
                    (1 - target)) * pt.pow(gamma)
    loss = F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(
        pred, target, reduction='none') * focal_weight
    loss = weight_reduce_loss(loss, weight, reduction, avg_factor)
    return loss
```

You can also experiment with [another focal loss version available](https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/28527749)

Comment: suppose to be softmax ? its multiclass

Answer (score 4):

I think OP would've gotten his answer by now. I am writing this for other people who might ponder upon this.

There in one problem in OPs implementation of Focal Loss:

1. `F_loss = self.alpha * (1-pt)**self.gamma * BCE_loss`

In this line, the same `alpha` value is multiplied with every class output probability i.e. (`pt`). Additionally, code doesn't show how we get `pt`. A very good implementation of Focal Loss could be find [here](https://amaarora.github.io/2020/06/29/FocalLoss.html). But this implementation is only for binary classification as it has `alpha` and `1-alpha` for two classes in `self.alpha` tensor.

In case of multi-class classification or multi-label classification, `self.alpha` tensor should contain number of elements equal to the total number of labels. The values could be inverse label frequency of labels or inverse label normalized frequency (just be cautious with labels which has 0 as frequency).

Answer (score 3):

I think the implementation in your question is wrong. The alpha is the class weight.

In cross entropy the class weight is the alpha_t as shown in the following expression:

[image]

you see that it is alpha_t rather than alpha.

In focal loss the fomular is
[image]

and we can see from [this popular Pytorch implementation](https://github.com/clcarwin/focal_loss_pytorch/blob/e11e75bad957aecf641db6998a1016204722c1bb/focalloss.py#L30-L31) the alpha acts the same way as class weight.

References:

1. https://amaarora.github.io/2020/06/29/FocalLoss.html#alpha-and-gamma
2. https://github.com/clcarwin/focal_loss_pytorch

Answer (score 2):

I was searching for this myself and found most implementations way to cumbersome. One can use pytorch's CrossEntropyLoss instead (and use ignore_index) and add the focal term. Keep in mind that class weights need to be applied after getting pt from CE so they must be applied separately rather than in CE as weights=alpha

```
class FocalLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, alpha=None, gamma=2, ignore_index=-100, reduction='mean'):
        super().__init__()
        # use standard CE loss without reducion as basis
        self.CE = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none', ignore_index=ignore_index)
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.reduction = reduction

    def forward(self, input, target):
        '''
        input (B, N)
        target (B)
        '''
        minus_logpt = self.CE(input, target)
        pt = torch.exp(-minus_logpt) # don't forget the minus here
        focal_loss = (1-pt)**self.gamma * minus_logpt

        # apply class weights
        if self.alpha != None:
            focal_loss *= self.alpha.gather(0, target)
        
        if self.reduction == 'mean':
            focal_loss = focal_loss.mean()
        elif self.reduction == 'sum':
            focal_loss = focal_loss.sum()
        return focal_loss
```